# SQL Syntax error on ASP.NET site

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net

I'm doing a Website using ASP.Net and using MySQL for the database. I am filling in a drop down list by doing a simple SELECT command, something I've already done at least 20 times in this project alone, but it keeps giving me an error.

I've already filled one drop down list and it is using the selected choice to fill the next drop down list, but it won't accept the data from the first list.

The SQL is:

```
SELECT EquipName FROM seniorschema.checkout WHERE Active=0 AND Email =hsnyder1@unca.edu;
```

I've tried LastName instead of email, checked and double checked the spelling, but it still doesn't work

Can someone figure it out?

Comment: quotes around hsnyder1@unca.edu ?

Comment: -1, have you attempted to debug this at all on your own?  The problem is pretty basic and if you look up some example queries you will probably see it very quickly.  Also - ANY time you get an error, post the exact error that you got.

Comment: It looks like you may need single quotes around `hsnyder1@unca.edu`.  You should use parameterized queries.

Comment: The error is probably telling you exactly what/where the problem is.  It's usually a good idea to read error messages instead of just trying random things.

Answer (score 2):

Is your `Email` value stored as a string (`varchar`)?  If the syntax is the same as MSSQL, I think your problem is that it's missing quotes.

```
SELECT EquipName FROM seniorschema.checkout WHERE Active=0 AND Email ='hsnyder1@unca.edu'
```